# OCMock does not mock class included via Cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods, ocmock

I'm using OCMock to mock DataFetcher class:

```
id dataFetcherMock = OCMClassMock([DataFetcher class]);
OCMStub([dataFetcherMock fetchSetupForCompany:[OCMArg any]
                                   completion:[OCMArg any]]).andCall(self, @selector(fetchSetupForCompany:completion:));
```

It was working fine when DataFetcher was a part of the project. But then we moved DataFetcher to a private Cocoapods. And the mocking stopped working. Method defined in andCall just never called anymore.

Can OCMock be used to mock classes added via cocoapods? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem was with the way I included testing target in pod file. What I had was:

```
target 'Service' do
    pod 'MTDates'
    pod 'libextobjc'
    pod 'DataFetcher'

    target 'ServiceTests' do
        pod 'OCMock'
        pod 'OHHTTPStubs'
    end
end
```

This resulted in DataFetcher class being linked to both target and thus it was duplicated in runtime.

I changed to

```
target 'Service' do
    pod 'MTDates'
    pod 'libextobjc'
    pod 'DataFetcher'
end

target 'ServiceTests' do
    pod 'OCMock'
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs'
end
```

This resolved the problem.